# Magento 1.9 Theme or Slider Extension

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm stuck in the design section. Couldn't manage to change the design. I have searched a lot but couldn't find Magento 1.9 free theme or slider extensions. As I have seen on youtube, they easily added extensions to Magento 1.9. But when I searched for it, I can't find out.

Please help me out

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I couldn't manage to change the homepage design.